# UWP: How do convert and convert back of Value Converters work?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an expander control where at a time only one expander is open at a time. If a user clicks on one expander, the other one collapses. The code is as follows:

I have a Converter.cs file with the following code

```
public class OppositeConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{

    return !(bool)value;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return !(bool)value;
}
}
```

I have  a MainPageViewModel.cs file with the following code:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
   public MainPageViewModel()
{

}
   private bool _isExpend;


   public bool IsExpend
   {
    get
    {
        return _isExpend;
    }
    set
    {
        _isExpend = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(isExpend));
    }
}
```

}

And i have a MainPage.xaml file

```
 <Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
 <Page.Resources>
        <local:OppositeConverter x:Key="OppositeConverter" />
  </Page.Resources>
 <StackPanel>
      <controls:Expander
       x:Name="Expander1"
       Content = "Expander 1 content"
       IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpend, Converter={StaticResource OppositConverter},Mode=TwoWay}">
   </controls:Expander>

   <controls:Expander
       x:Name="Expander2"
       Content = "Expander 2 content"
       IsExpanded="{x:Bind IsExpend, Mode=TwoWay}">
   </controls:Expander>     
</StackPanel>
```

Can i get help understanding how converters work here ? When is convert called and when is convertback called? Why does only the first expander use the converter and not the second? I would really appreciate help in understanding the flow of this code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is convert called and when is convertback called?

The `OppositeConverter` class allows you to convert the format of your data between the source and the target by inheriting from `IValueConverter`. When clicking on a control to change the state, we use
`OppositeConverter` to set the state value of another control to the opposite value.

The `Convert` method is called when you click the second control. The work flow is like this:

1. Click the second control to expand or collapse it, the value of `_isExpend` of the second control will be changed and `RaisePropertyChanged` method will be called to notify the value is changed.
2. The first control gets an opposite value of `_isExpend` of the second control  by calling the `Convert` method, which makes the status of collapse or expansion of the first control is opposite to the second control.

The `ConvertBack` method is called when you click the frist control. The work flow is like this:

1. Click the first control to expand or collapse it, the `ConvertBack` method is called to get an opposite value of `_isExpend`.
2. The `RaisePropertyChanged` method will be called to notify the value is changed, and the second control get the value of `_isExpend` opposited to the value of `_isExpend` of the first control.

> Why does only the first expander use the converter and not the second?

One Converter can reverse the value of the other control once, which is exactly what we need. If you use it in both two controls, the two Converter will make the value of the two controls same, and the state of the two controls will remain the same when you click one of them.